# How to solve "Could not execute systemctl: at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-invoke line 142" error when trying to start ejabberd service?

Tags: 22.04, systemd, services, ejabberd

I have tried to start `ejabberd` service with `systemctl` in Ubuntu 22.04, but I keep getting:

```
Could not execute systemctl: at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-invoke line 142
```

Comment: How do you try to start the service exactly ?

Comment: This is a known `init-system-helpers` bug that has been confirmed but hasn't been resolved yet: [Cannot configure krb5-kdc on Ubuntu Jammy 22.04.01, "Could not execute systemctl: at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-invoke line 142."](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/init-system-helpers/+bug/2003756) I suggest that you sign yourself as affected by the bug and also subscribe to the bug's notifications. This way the bug report will get more heat (so it should be resolved sooner) and you'll also get notified about any changes in its status.

Answer (score 0):

If you arrived here trying to install a package, you can fix it temporary while we wait for a fix allowing you to install the package.

Remember to change `<package>` with the name of the package you're getting the problem.

- Look on `/var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.postinst`
- Edit that file and    comment the lines with the `deb-systemd-invoke`
  commands. If they're    inside a if/then which will be empty place a
  `echo '1'` to avoid    problems with the empty if.
- Run the apt install another time which should finish the installation
- Edit the `/var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.postinst` another time and leave it as it was before.
- Enable the service `/lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable <package>`